# Refresh a chart's information by seconds, not a button

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, d3pie.js

I am currently using d3pie to create a chart based on information I get from a .cgi file. I want to make the chart more dynamic and real-time, and essentially get the data every 5 seconds and refresh the chart based on the new data. There is a function in the api of this site called redraw(), which does redraw the chart. This is how the site used it:

http://d3pie.org/website/examples/refresh.html

I was wondering if there was anyway I could not be dependent on the refresh button, but instead, just have the redraw() method called every 5 or 10 seconds. For example, instead of:

```
$(function() {
    $("#refreshBtn").on("click", function(e) {
        pie.redraw();
    });
});
```

I'd like to have something like this:

```
$(function() {
    //every five seconds {
        pie.redraw();
    });
});
```

Is it possible to do something like this?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish your task by utilizing [JavaScript Timing Events](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp). For instance, you can do something like this:

`window.setInterval(function() { pie.redraw(); }, 5000);`

This will run your redraw `function` every 5 seconds.

Comment: It's weird because I already have the line in a function like this:

`<script>
setInterval(function () {
        $.get("/cgi/unit_test_motd.cgi", function(data)
        {
        alert(data);
        var a  = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
        window.setInterval(pie.redraw(), 5000);
});                              
}, 5000);            
         
</script> `

I'd think that the redraw method would already be called every 5 seconds, right? Maybe it's just something I cannot control?

Comment: The redraw method seems to be called every 30 seconds, because thats when the pie actually refreshes. Not every 5 seconds for some reason.

Comment: @user2677095 Check to make sure there aren't any errors in the console. Removing the `$.get` command (since I don't obviously have the unit_test_motd.cgi path), was working every 5 seconds as per the code. Also, try updating the code to what I've modified mine to be above.

Comment: Never mind, I had a refresh tag in html and I think that was interfering with the code. Regardless, your code worked!! Thanks a lot!